# How to create default Layout file in DoxyWizard

Tags: doxygen

I read that running doxygen with -1 option creates a default DoxygenLayout.xml file..

However, I am using Doxywizard instead of the command line,, and I'm not sure how to do this in Doxywizard..

Even if I do the following, it doesn't generate any layout file:

[image]

How do I generate a DoxygenLayout.xml file using DoxyWizard?

Answer (score 3):

I would not expect Doxywizard to *generate* a layout file.  The option you have highlighted is where you *tell* Doxywizard about the layout file you have generated separately.

You will need to generate a layout with that `-l` (minus ell, not minus one) option to the command line invocation of doxygen.  This is just a one-off requirement.

I would suggest you use a non-default name for the generated file. Thus I suggest you open a command line and run something like:

`doxygen -l myDoxlayout.xml`

then enter `myDoxlayout.xml` into that field in Doxywizard.